# HTML datetime-local input field, not being able to select time

Tags: html, datetime, mean-stack, datetime-local

Some background - I've got a MEAN stack timesheet application that I'm hosting on my local network on Apache server and accessing on different machines connected to the network. **The machines are not connected to the internet.**

There's a `datetime-local` input field in the HTML of the application, while some machines are able to select date and time properly one of them isn't. I can't select the time of the current date but I'm able to do that for yesterday's date or few hours before. But in no case I am able to select the current time which is totally possible on the other machines that are accessing the same page at the same time.

I believe this issue arises due to the machine not being connected to the internet and is using some other time zone but since I'm using `datetime-local` which disregards the time zone information as opposed to plain `datetime`, I doubt that would cause an issue.

Would connecting to the internet and syncing the time in the settings solve the issue as I'll need to take several permissions before connecting the machine to internet or is there something else I'm missing? Please help, comment if you need more info.